# PrimeFaces Datatable Implementation

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to add run datatable project my class file

```
package org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.lang.String;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped

public class Car implements Serializable {
    private final static String[] colors;

    private final static String[] manufacturers;

    private List<CarTemp> cars;

    static {
        colors = new String[10];
        colors[0] = "Black";
        colors[1] = "White";
        colors[2] = "Green";
        colors[3] = "Red";
        colors[4] = "Blue";
        colors[5] = "Orange";
        colors[6] = "Silver";
        colors[7] = "Yellow";
        colors[8] = "Brown";
        colors[9] = "Maroon";

        manufacturers = new String[10];
        manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";
        manufacturers[1] = "BMW";
        manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";
        manufacturers[3] = "Audi";
        manufacturers[4] = "Renault";
        manufacturers[5] = "Opel";
        manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";
        manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";
        manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";
        manufacturers[9] = "Ford";
    }


    public Car() {
         cars = new ArrayList<CarTemp>();

        populateRandomCars(cars, 50);
    }

    private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {

       CarTemp a=  new CarTemp(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor());
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
            list.add(a);

    }

    public List<CarTemp> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }

    private String getRandomColor() {
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomManufacturer() {
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomModel() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }
}
```

this is my CarTemp.Java file

```
package org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking;
 public class CarTemp {

    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String color;

    public CarTemp(String model, int year, String manufacturer, String color) {
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:

> java: method populateRandomCars in class org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking.Car cannot be applied to given types;
>         required: java.util.List,int
>         found: java.util.List,int
>         reason: actual argument java.util.List cannot be converted to java.util.List by method invocation conversion
>
> java: no suitable method found for add(org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking.CarTemp)
>       method java.util.List.add(int,org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking.Car) is not applicable
>         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>       method java.util.List.add(org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking.Car) is not applicable
>         (actual argument org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking.CarTemp cannot be converted to org.springframework.webflow.samples.booking.Car by method invocation conversion)

it looks like the class can be added to the list.
In primefaces datatable documentation they do not have any more explanation about how their system is working.
I can not figure out what wrong I did.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what `populateRandomCars` is expecting as parameters, and what you are passing in to it

```
 ....

 public Car() {
     cars = new ArrayList<CarTemp>();
     populateRandomCars(cars, 50); // (2)
 }

 private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) { // (1)
 ...
 }

 ....
```

(1) The first parameter is expecting a List of type Car --> `List<Car>`
(2)  And you are passing a List of type CarTemp --> `List<CarTemp>`

So you have to modify `populateRandomCars` to this signature

```
 private void populateRandomCars(List<CarTemp> list, int size) {}
```